# PrestaShop $link ->getProductLink($product) gives incorrect URL

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I'm generating my product links in custom ajax powered module with `$link -> getProductLink($product)`

it's generating a URL like http://example.com/prestashop/2-blouse.html

which is throwing an error saying

> [Debug] This page has moved Please use the following URL instead:
>   http://example.com/prestashop/blouses/2-blouse.html

How do I avoid the same whithout Set _PS_MODE_DEV_ to false in config/defines.inc.php.

Thanks

P.S: I'm using prestashop 1.7

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Comment: Why would you even want this? It doesn't matter in development mode, you shouldn't run this mode in production anyway.

Comment: because SEO, Google consider the follow link : **exemple.com/product** and not **exemple.com/category/product**

Comment: Same problem here, Link::getproductLink() returns link that redirects to 404...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out [this](https://github.com/faktiva/prestashop-clean-urls) (free) module. 
But to awnser your question `{$link->getProductLink($smarty.get.id_product, $smarty.get.id_product.link_rewrite)|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}`